# New document gets wrong content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, content-type

Within a site collection "x" I have got a document library which contains multiple content types. Each content type is managed at site collection level and has a .dotx template file assigned to it.

The .dotx file should be adjustable within SharePoint so it is stored within a document library in de root site collection. The template file has got the content type Document assigned to it.

When I want to create a new document in the document library in site collection "x" I click on New and select the content type for my document.

Let's say I clicked content type "Document A". Word opens and in the document information panel I see the correct content type "Document A" and the columns associated with it. When I save my document all goes well.

Now I want to create a document with content type "Document B". I click on New and select content type "Document B". When Word opens and I look in my document information panel I see that the content type again is "Document A". The columns in my document information panel are also the columns assiocated with content type "Document A".

It doesn't mather which content type I pick, every document gets content type "Document A" assigned to it.

Anyone experienced the same behaviour before and knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Document templates will carry a lot of xml data with them and sometimes it won't get overwritten. You can see them when using word:
File --> Info: Inspect Document --> Check for issues: Inspect Document
You will see what data this document carries within.
And you can delete this information also in this view.
Remove that data and upload template for the content type again.

Answer (score 0):

Save the dotx file as your desired content type, then your new document will be the same content type as the dotx file.  So you wll need to add your content types to the library where you are storing your dotx template files.